# Lines Intersect method not working correctly

Tags: java, math, physics, algebra, calculus

I'm working on some vector math, and I need to calculate the normal vector of a polygon.
My code:

```
    //p is a parameter, is a Vec2, second point on first line
    double[][] vert = getVerticies(); //[any length, # of verticies][2]
    for(int i = 0; i < vert.length; i++) {
        Vec2 cm = Vec2.ZERO_VEC;//first point on first line, always is <0, 0> as it is the origin
        Vec2 rcm = getCM(); // just used to get relative positions.
        Vec2 v1 = cm.sub(new Vec2(vert[i])); //the first point in one of all edges of the shape, second line
        Vec2 v2 = cm.sub(new Vec2(i == vert.length - 1 ? vert[0] : vert[i + 1])); // the second point on the second  line.
        double den = (v2.getY() - v1.getY()) * (p.getX() - cm.getX()) - (v2.getX() - v1.getX()) * (p.getY() - cm.getY());
        if(den == 0D) {
            continue;
        }
        double a = ((v2.getX() - v1.getX()) * (cm.getY() - v1.getY()) - (v2.getY() - v1.getY()) * (cm.getX() - v1.getX())) / den;
        double b = ((p.getX() - cm.getX()) * (cm.getY() - v1.getY()) - (p.getY() - cm.getY()) * (cm.getX() - v1.getX())) / den;
        if(a >= 0D && a <= 1D && b >= 0D && b <= 1D) {
            Vec2 mid = v2.add(v2.sub(v1).scale(0.5D)); //this is just normal vector calculation stuff, I know the error isn't here, as if it was, it would return a non-unit-scale vector.
            return mid.uscale(); //hats the vector, returns
        }
    }
    return p; // return the parameter, second point on first line, used as a contingency, should never actually run, as the first line is fully contained in the lines were testing against
```

I've done some debugging, and I just don't see what's happening. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my math? It just seems to flow absolutely fine, but the math just doesn't seem right. My goal with this code is to determine the index of the two verticies that my line intersects.

Comment: Input? Expected result? Actual result? This would benefit greatly from being broken down into smaller pieces (methods). (On a side note, I'm pretty sure there's no calculus here, only vector algebra.)

Comment: I think I figured out my issue, you know how when you try to explain an issue you figure it out? It was that I'm testing for line segments, when I need to be testing for vector "rays", and/or use ray tracing.

Comment: Wait. It's a surface in the 2-d plane. Wouldn't the normal always be along the z-axis?

Comment: @jpmc26 Your thinking of torque, and in the case of 2D, it is usually just represented as a +/- value consisting of the magnitude of torque. Normal vectors are used in physics for collision responses.

Comment: A [normal vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) is the vector perpendicular to the object. Since your object is a polygon (2-dimensional) lying in the xy-plane, the perpendicular vector would have to point away from the xy-plane. No? Maybe if you're not taking the normal to the polygon but to a line, then it could be 2d, but I believe the normal of a surface must be 3d. So I'm missing something, you're not computing the normal of the polygon, or the normal would be along the z-axis. (Also, torque is roughly the rotational equivalent of a force, which I don't see referenced.)

Answer (score 0):

Oops, figured it out by virtue of attempted to explain it. I need to be ray tracing, or use ray intersection testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to calculate the normal of a polygon, it looks like you are trying to do something overly complicated. You can simply use cross product of two adjacent edges to get it. Even better, with a simple math [explained here](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/areas/areas.htm), you don't even need to calculate the edge vectors. Just take the cross product of each adjacent vertex pair and sum them up:

[image]